# TypeError: $(...).msDropDown is not a function

Tags: jquery

I am getting type error in jquery , please help me

TypeError: `$(...).msDropDown` is not a function

```
$("#time_zone").msDropDown();
```

replace `$` by `jQuery` but same error occure

```
 $(document).ready(function(arg) {
     $("#time_zone").msDropDown();
     $("#time_zone").hide();
 });
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Which browser are you using? Why do you think `msDropDown` should exist?

Comment: Did you include the `script src` for it?

Comment: Because DOM elements do not have a `.msDropDown()` method. If you are using a library please say so

Comment: there are a number of different reasons this can occur. Loading jQuery more than once, forgetting to load plugin file or bad path to plugin file, noConflict being used in page (very common in wordpress and other CMS's), incorrect code loading order. You need to isolate these issues and gather as much detail as you can

Comment: yes i m forgetting to include jquery.dd.js file where msDropDown() is declare so this type of error occured..
now I m including, no error occured

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using an external js file for dropdown right ?
  If So that error is due to not including your js file .
  You should call your external js above just or above your code snippet.

eg:-

```
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>javascripts/msDropDown.js"></script>
```

then your code comes below

```
$(document).ready(function(arg) {
     $("#time_zone").msDropDown();
     $("#time_zone").hide();
 });
```

Hope this helps you !!
thank you

Comment: yes only one possibilities,but he could try atleast this suggestion too